# How to change color representation in bar3 (MATLAB) to represent data from another variable?

Tags: matlab

I have the `32x32` matrix `LagsX` which contains data that I want to plot in 3d using `bar3`. I want to be able to change the color of the bars to represent the data in another `32x32` matrix called `CrossCorrX`. So that I actually represent 4d-data.

I've tried to access `ZData` of the bar, that I get from plotting with `bar3(LagsX)` and replacing the `ZData` from `bar3(CrossCorX)`.
But I recieved the following error:

> Invalid or deleted object.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
b1 = bar3(crossCorrX);  colorbar
b = bar3(lagsX); 
for k = 1:length(b)
    b(k).CData = b1(k).ZData;
    b(k).FaceColor = 'interp';
end
```

I recieved the error in the line `b(k).CData = b1(k).ZData;`.

Do you have suggestions how to do it? Why does the error appear? 
Suggestions for using other functions than `bar3` would be appreciated as well.

I'm using MATLAB R2015a.

**EDIT**

I have understood my problem, just needed to add figure; again. My new problem is, that wherever LagsX == 0, the color that represents CrossCorX is displayed as it was zero, even though it is different. Any tips of how can I overcome this?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: I guess that `Zdata` are single values, while colour should be RGB 3 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is occurring because you are overwriting the 1st plot with the 2nd, hence its `ZData` property is not accessible anymore.

To overcome this you can simply assign a figure to each of the `bar3` plot and that should work.

Example with random data:

```
clear
clc
close all

A = rand(10,10);
A2 = rand(10,10);

figure(1)
b1= bar3(A);

figure(2)
b = bar3(A2);

hcb = colorbar;

for k = 1:length(b)
    b(k).CData = b1(k).ZData;
    b(k).FaceColor = 'interp';
end
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you are right. My only problem now is that some of the colors don't much the values, I think it's somehow interpreted and I dont know how to change it and show thae exact values.

Comment: Following you example - if for example I have that the value of A(10,10) is one, then the entire bar should be yellow. but it's not. I think it's somehow interpreted, and becasue my X and Y axis are descrete (representing names) I dont want it to be interpreted. is there any way I can change it?